# Custom weight initiatlization in conv1d pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to create custom weights in conv1d as follows:

```
import torch
from torch import nn
conv = nn.Conv1d(1,1,kernel_size=2)
K = torch.Tensor([[[0.5, 0.5]]])
with torch.no_grad():
conv.weight = K
```

But I am getting the error

```
"File “D:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pytorchcuda102\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py”, line 611, in setattr
raise TypeError(“cannot assign ‘{}’ as parameter ‘{}’ "
TypeError: cannot assign ‘torch.FloatTensor’ as parameter ‘weight’ (torch.nn.Parameter or None expected)”
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You were close. Note that you do not need to call 'with torch.no_grad()' since in the weight assignment process there will be no gradient computed.
All you need to do is to remove it and call 'conv.weight.data' instead of 'conv.weight' so that you can access the underlying parameter values.
See the fixed code below:

```
import torch
from torch import nn
conv = nn.Conv1d(1,1,kernel_size=2)
K = torch.Tensor([[[0.5, 0.5]]])
conv.weight.data = K
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the discussion [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/custom-weight-initialization/20544/7), update your code to include `torch.nn.Parameter()`, which basically makes the weight recognizable as a parameter in optimizer.

```
import torch
from torch import nn
conv = nn.Conv1d(1,1,kernel_size=2)
K = torch.tensor([[[0.5, 0.5]]]) #use one dimensional as per your conv layer
conv.weight = nn.Parameter(K) #use nn.parameters
```

for Bigger and complex models you can see this toy example which uses pytorch `state_dict()` method.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision

net = torchvision.models.resnet18(pretrained=True)

pretrained_dict = net.state_dict()
conv_weights = pretrained_dict['conv1.weight'] #64,3,7,7

new = torch.tensor((), dtype=torch.int32)
new = new.new_ones(conv_weights.shape) #assigning all ones

pretrained_dict['conv1.weight'] = new


net.load_state_dict(pretrained_dict)
param = list(net.parameters())

print(param[0])
```

Comment: You'll have to set K as 3 dimensional otherwise you'd get the following error: RuntimeError: weight should have at least three dimensions

Comment: i didnt recieve any at pytorch 1.3.1

Comment: but yes you are right as output of `print(conv.weight.data.shape)` is `torch.Size([1, 1, 2])`

Comment: Try to apply the conv layer to some tensor and you'll get this error. For example: conv(torch.randn(1,1,10))

Comment: yes you are right. that's why i prefer to use `net.state_dict()`.